# Edge browser: Jerking movement at the end of transition only when skew and translate are used together

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a position:absolute element behind my anchor tag. I animate that element with simple css transition when the anchor tag is hovered.

On Edge only, there's this funky jerky movement at the very end of the transition.

I tried adding translateX(0) to both hover and normal states, but that did not remove the jerky move at the end.

Here's the button html:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82, .21, .27, .81);
}

.button-bg {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .4s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82, .21, .27, .81);
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid #212121;
}

a.button:hover .button-bg {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(2) scaleX(1.4) skewY(10deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(2) scaleX(1.4) skewY(10deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<a class="button case-readmore" href="#">        
    Read Case
    <span class="button-bg"></span>
    </a>
```

Expected result can be seen with Chrome, Firefox, Internet explorer etc.

Weird bugfest can be seen with Edge, where the element transforms properly and at the very end of the transform jerks quickly to the right.

If I remove the skew part of the transition, theres no more jerking.

Comment: Please do mention the exact versions of the browsers tested, so that it might be easier to reproduce the issue. Also, consider adding runnable example using  http://jsfiddle.net, http://codepen.io, http://plnkr.co etc or use 'stack snippets' by using by clicking the [<>] toolbar button in the edit section

Comment: When you are adding any property on hover you need to add default values before hover of elements.

Comment: @MayankGupta it's not needed for transform, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599866/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the default values before the hover. There is probably an interpolation issue.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82, .21, .27, .81);
}

.button-bg {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(1) scaleX(1) skewY(0deg);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .4s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82, .21, .27, .81);
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid #212121;
}

a.button:hover .button-bg {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(2) scaleX(1.4) skewY(10deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<a class="button case-readmore" href="#">        
    Read Case
    <span class="button-bg"></span>
    </a>
```

Related:

[Weird behavior when rotating an element on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52589511/8620333)

[matrix not equal to translate and rotate combination in css transform animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53956599/8620333)

[why this keyframe animation form this animation effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52663773/8620333)

Comment: This was indeed it. I tried scaleX(1) before asking, but did not specify the skewY or scaleY because I saw the jerk happen sideways.

For some reason that made me assume it must be a scaleX issue alone.

Comment: @Jussi it's not really the scale, but an interpolation issue because technically the browser should add scaleX(1) by default, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599866/8620333